# Prove that this field is not complete

Tags: calculus, field-theory

Given $F \subset \mathbb{R}$ and the $F$ is ordered field, $F = \{a + b \sqrt{2}\ |\ a,b \in \mathbb{Q} \}$

Prove that $F$ is not a complete field,

Hint : Consider the sets $A = \{a \in F\ |\ a^2 <3\text{ or }a<0\}$ and $B = \{b \in F\ |\ b^2>3 , b>0\}$

I assumed that $F$ is complete field so there is $c$ such that for every element $a$ in $A$ , $a \leq c$ and for every element in $b$ in $B$ , $b\geq c$, and also true that $c^2 <3 $ or $c^2=3$ or $c^2>3$,

when $c^2=3$ one need to prove that $\sqrt{3} \not \in F$.

and that other cases will produces contradictions !

But i don't know how to prove it ??

Comment: As it stands, $A = (0,\sqrt3)$ and $B = (-\infty, -\sqrt3)\cup (\sqrt3, \infty)$. Did you mean something like $A = \{a\in F\mid a^2<3 \text{ or } a<0\}$ and $B = \{b\in F\mid b^2>3\text{ and } b>0\}$?

Comment: @Arthur yes, i did it but some one edit the question and removed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume, for contradiction, that $\sqrt3\in F$. By definition of $F$, that means that there are rational $a, b$ such that $\sqrt3 = a+b\sqrt2$. We get
$$
\sqrt3 = a+b\sqrt2\\
3 = a^2 + 2ab\sqrt2 + 2b
$$
Since $2ab\sqrt2$ is the only irrational term in the last line (unless it's $0$), it must be $0$. Therefore we either have $a = 0$ or we have $b = 0$. But $b = 0$ implies $\sqrt3 = a$ is rational, so that can't be true. And $a = 0$ gives $\sqrt3 = b\sqrt2$. Multiply both sides by $\sqrt 2$, and we get $\sqrt6 = 2b$, so $\sqrt 6$ is rational. But this can't be true either.

Therefore we are forced to conclude that $\sqrt 3 \notin F$.

Comment: great answer and very helpful, but how to prove that $c^2>3$ is contradiction ?

Comment: Because if $c^2 > 3$, then by the density of $F$, there is a $b\in B$ such that $b<c$.

Comment: i know, but we can't you words like dense, proving is only be sets and supremum

Comment: @Ahmad In that case (assuming $c>0$), consider $b = \dfrac{c + \frac3c}{2}$. It's not too much work to show that $3<b^2$ and $b<c$, so $b\in B$ and $c$ fails to be a lower bound for $B$. For $c^2<\sqrt3$ (still assuming $c>0$), the corresponding argument applies, with $a = \dfrac{2}{\frac1c + \frac c3}$.